# Making sentences from words

Tags: python, text, nlp

Is there a way to get back sentences from broken up words? For example I have the text below:

```
THIS IS
A TITLE
hello my 
name
is Sam
Some of the text is formatted.
But others
are
not
```

What I am doing right now is providing some structure to it.

- If I see upper case characters, I assume that it is a title and then I get all the upper case letters in sequence and form a title.
- If I see an uppercase character and and full stop some characters later, then that would be one full sentence.

The result I would like from above is this:

```
THIS IS A TITLE
----
hello my name is Sam
----
Some of the text is formatted.
----
But others are not
----
```

Where above '----' is a sentence. (Formatting)

However, there seems to be a lot of corner cases I would have to account for.
Is there Natural Language processing I could do to make this easier?

Comment: What is document_text_detection(), where is it from ? it should have some info regarding the output

Comment: It is from the Google Vision API. I checked the info, It can only format it like that since it is reading text from an image file and outputting it. It can't understand what the text means.

Comment: I have removed non relevant information (E.g The google vision API).